# Time semantics between KStream and KTable

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to build the following topology:

1. Using Debezium Connectors, I am pulling 2 tables (let's called them tables A, and DA). As per DBZ, the topics where the table rows are stored have the structure { before: "...", after: "..." }.
2. First steps in my topology are to create "clean" KStreams off these two "table" topics. The sub-topology there looks roughly like this:

```java
private static KStream<String, TABLE_A.Value> getTableARowByIdStream(
    StreamsBuilder builder, Properties streamsConfig) {
  return builder
      .stream("TABLE_A", Consumed.withTimestampExtractor(Application::getRowDate))
      .filter((key, envelope) -> [ some filtering condition ] )
      .map((key, envelope) -> [ maps to TABLE_A.Value ] )
      .through(tableRowByIdTopicName);
}
```

3. Notice that I am assigning the record time explicitly because the table rows will be CDC'ed "years" after they were originally published. What the function is doing at the moment is faking the time starting at 2010-01-01 and, using an `AtomicInteger`, adding 1 millisecond for each consumed entity. It does this for tables A but it doesn't for DA (I will explain why later).
4. Phase 2 of the topology is to build 1 KTable based on the "cleaned" topic for table A, like this:

```java
private static KTable<String, EntityInfoList> getEntityInfoListById(
    KStream<String, TABLE_A.Value> tableAByIdStream) {
  return tableAByIdStream
      .map((key, value) -> [ some mapping ] )
      .groupByKey()
      .aggregate(() -> [ builds up a EntityInfoList object ] ));
}
```

5. Finally, with th KTable ready, I'm joining them with the KStream over DA like so:

```java
private static KStream<String, OutputTopicEntity> getOutputTopicEntityStream(
    KStream<String, Table_DA.Value> tableDAStream,
    KTable<String, EntityInfoList> tableA_KTable) {

  KStream<String, Table_DA>[] branches = tableDAStream.branch(
      (key, value) -> [ some logic ],
      (key, value) -> true);

  KStream<String, OutputTopicEntity> internalAccountRefStream = branches[0]
      .join(
          tableA_KTable,
          (streamValue, tableValue) -> [ some logic to build a list of OutputTopicEntity ])
      .flatMap((key, listValue) -> [ some logic to flatten it ]));

   [ similar logic with branch[1] ]
}
```

My problem is, despite the fact that I am "faking" the time for records coming from the Table_A topic (I've verified that they are referencing 2010/01/01 using kafkacat) and entries in Table_DA (the stream side of the join) have timestamps around today '2019/08/14'), it doesn't seem like Kafka Streams is holding reading any of the entries from Table_DA KStream until it has ingested all records from Table_A into the KTable.

As a result of that, I don't have all the "join hits" that I was expecting and it is also nondeterministic. My understanding based on this sentence from [What are the differences between KTable vs GlobalKTable and leftJoin() vs outerJoin()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975755/what-are-the-differences-between-ktable-vs-globalktable-and-leftjoin-vs-outerj) was the opposite:

> For stream-table join, Kafka Stream align record processing ordered based on record timestamps. Thus, the update to the table are aligned with the records of you stream.

My experience so far is this is not happening. I can also easily see how my application continues churning through the Table_A topic way after it has consumed all entries in Table_DA stream (it happens to be 10 times smaller).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should really make the code smaller as it's too much to digest and have little to do with Kafka Streams most of the time. It currently looks like "why isn't this code working?" question and could be closed.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I disagree. I'm providing the full topology just for context and to help whoever knows what the time semantics should be to understand the full picture. I'm definitively not asking why this code is not working because it is working perfectly fine, except for the stream vs ktable consumption priority

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timestamp synchronization is best effort before 2.1.0 release (cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3514).

As of 2.1.0, timestamps are synchronized strictly. However, if one input does not have any data, Kafka Streams will "enforce" processing as described in [KIP-353](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-353%3A+Improve+Kafka+Streams+Timestamp+Synchronization) to avoid blocking forever. If you have bursty inputs and want to "block" processing for some time if one input has no data, you can increase configuration parameter `max.task.idle.ms` (default is `0`) as introduced in 2.1.0 via KIP-353.